# Reading config.json in vNext without Startup.cs in Beta8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I don't have a startup file because my DAL is in another project.  I just want to be able to read the config.json file in that project to get the connection string.

I tried instantiating a Configuration class(which seems to be in beta4), and using it to Get the connection string but it keeps passing back a null value.  Anyone have any insight?

Folder Structure:

```
=>MyProject.DAL
BlogContext.cs
config.json
project.json
```

This is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "MyProject.DAL Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Admin" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23409",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23409",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23409",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23409",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23409"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "MyProject.Entities": "1.0.0-*"
  }
    }
```

This is config.json

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SolutionPub;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

}

BlogContext.cs

```
public class BlogContext: DbContext
{

    public BlogContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        var connectionString = configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system doesn't know that you want to use `config.json`. You have to tell it.

```
 var configuration = new Configuration();
 configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
 var connectionString = configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");
```

If it's in another project, you should first ask yourself why that project is directly accessing the configuration file instead of having it passed from the startup project. But if you really want to do it that way, then just modify the path to the file in the `AddJsonFile` call.